# c: Convert ipv6 address to string at compile time

Tags: c, gcc, ipv6

This is a longshot, but I'm wondering if there are any tricks to convert a constant ipv6 address string into two 64 bit integers at *compile time*.  (this is on an embedded system, and thus runtime and memory are both valuable commodities).  Ideally the code would look something like:

```
const uint64_t addr[2] = { IPV6_TO_UINT64S("::ffff:192.168.1.1") };
```

which would produce:

```
const uint64_t addr[2] = { 0x0000000000000000ULL, 0x0000ffffc0a80101ULL };
```

Comment: I would write another program that you use to pre-process the source code.

Comment: Along the same lines, I'd suggest you put those IPv6 constants in a JSON config file and write a template header file. Use a program to process the constants and fill in the blanks in the template. Use any programming language and template system you like.

Comment: You could do it at *coding* time.  That might be via a code generator, or by the kind of hand-computation you seem to have performed.

Comment: If you're using a build configuration system such as CMake or the Autotools, you could conceivably put the computation there, and feed it into your build via a macro definition.

Comment: Your example mixes well-known decimal values with ipv6 which is hex.

Comment: @stark check [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) `::ffff:192.0.2.128 represents the IPv4 address 192.0.2.128.`

Comment: @Schwern *I'd suggest you put those IPv6 constants in a JSON config file and write a template header file.* C doesn't have templates, and why introduce an extraneous dependency on JSON processing?

Comment: @Schwern: I'm not sure I understand the advantage of using a config file vs just a script that just replaces the string in place.

Comment: @John Using a template means less parsing is involved, and you can use a pre-existing template library, or make up something really simple. Using a config file makes it easier to adjust the values. For example, y2038 has to probe the system to learn its limits. It then uses [a tiny Perl program](https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038/blob/master/perl/Time-y2038/munge_config) to fill in [a template header file](https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038/blob/master/perl/Time-y2038/y2038/time64_limits.h.in) to produce [time64_limits.h](https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038/blob/master/time64_limits.h).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Not C++ templates, fill in the blank templates. JSON is ubiquitous and no great dependency.

Comment: Given that it is a compile-time constant, what is wrong with doing it by hand as you have and assigning it as you have in the second fragment?  The number of times you are going to have to do this is probably hardly worth the effort of making it work.  If you want the reader to understand the code, include the string format in a comment.

Comment: Have a look at "man inet_pton" on Linux.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I wrote a simple script that expands the macro in place, which can be run prior to compiling.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing I'd recommend writing a template header file (not C++ templates, but fill-in-the-blank templates), putting the human-readable values in a config file, and using a small program to fill in the blanks.

For example, the config file might be in JSON. (This is obviously overkill for a single value, I'm just showing the technique.)

```
{
    "addr": "::ffff:192.168.1.1"
}
```

You could use an existing template language, or make up your own. For something as simple as a C header file, you can get away with something very simple.

```
const uint64_t addr[2] = { %%addr%% };
```

And the code to read the config and process the template simple in a ubiquitous scripting language like Ruby.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'

template, config_file = ARGV[0..1]

# Load the config file
config = JSON.load( File.new(config_file) )

# Ensure missing config variables throw an error
config.default_proc = proc do |hash, key|
    throw "Config key '#{key}' is missing from #{config_file}"
end

# ...do whatever processing on the config variables you want...

# Fill in the template.
IO.foreach(template) { |line|
    puts line.gsub(/%%(.*?)%%/) { config[$1] }
}
```

I employ this technique in the y2038 library. It has to probe the system to determine the limits of time.h, then encode those limits into a custom header file. [munge_config](https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038/blob/master/perl/Time-y2038/munge_config) reads the configuration values (from the build system, not from a JSON config, but the result is the same: a hash), and fills in the template. This is the [time64_limits.h.in template](https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038/blob/master/perl/Time-y2038/y2038/time64_limits.h.in) and an example of [a resulting time64_limits.h header file](https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038/blob/master/time64_limits.h).

Comment: thanks for the response, but while this is interesting, for my purposes it's faster and more convenient to update the addresses in place (one of my main goals was readability).

Comment: @John You could add the original value as a comment.